# topoplot in ggplot2 – 2D visualisation of e.g. EEG data

Tags: r, ggplot2, eeglab

**Can `ggplot2` be used to produce a so-called *topoplot* (often used in neuroscience)?**

[image: topoplot]

Sample data:

```
   label          x          y     signal
1     R3 0.64924459 0.91228430  2.0261520
2     R4 0.78789621 0.78234410  1.7880972
3     R5 0.93169511 0.72980685  0.9170998
4     R6 0.48406513 0.82383895  3.1933129
```

**[Full sample data.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d8975f76f5bcde7bd455#file-topoplot_sample_data-csv)**

Rows represent individual electrodes. Columns `x` and `y` represent the projection into 2D space and the column `signal` is essentially the z-axis representing voltage measured at a given electrode.

`stat_contour` doesn't work, apparently due to unequal grid.

`geom_density_2d` only provides a density estimation of `x` and `y`.

`geom_raster` is one not fitted for this task or I must be using it incorrectly since it quickly runs out of memory.

Smoothing (like in the image on the right) and head contours (nose, ears) aren't necessary.

I want to avoid Matlab and transforming the data so that it fits this or that toolbox.

The closest I've been able to get to my objective is via

```
library(colorRamps)
ggplot(channels, aes(x, y, z = signal)) + stat_summary_2d() + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=matlab.like(20))
```

which produces an image like this:

[image]

I've tried @alexforrence's approach with full data and this is the result:

[image: @alexforrence's approach]

It's a great start but there are a couple of issues:

1. The last call (`ggplot()`) takes about 40 seconds on an Intel i7 4790K while Matlab toolboxes manage to generate these almost instantly; my ‘emergency solution’ above takes about a second.
2. As you can see, the upper and lower border of the central part appear to be ‘sliced’ – I'm not sure what causes this but it could be the third issue.
3. I'm getting these warnings:

   ```
   1: Removed 170235 rows containing non-finite values (stat_contour). 
   2: Removed 170235 rows containing non-finite values (stat_contour).
   ```

Comparison between two plots produced with different `interp(xo, yo)` and `stat_contour(binwidth)` values:

[image: comparison between different values]

Ragged edges if one chooses low `interp(xo, yo)`, in this case `xo`/`yo = seq(0, 1, length = 100)`:

[image: ragged edges]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a potential start:

First, we'll attach some packages. I'm using [akima](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/akima/index.html) to do linear interpolation, though it looks like EEGLAB uses some sort of spherical interpolation [here?](http://home.uni-leipzig.de/biocog/content/widmann/eeglab-plugins/) (the data was a little sparse to try it).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(akima)
library(reshape2)
```

Next, reading in the data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   label          x          y     signal
1     R3 0.64924459 0.91228430  2.0261520
2     R4 0.78789621 0.78234410  1.7880972
3     R5 0.93169511 0.72980685  0.9170998
4     R6 0.48406513 0.82383895  3.1933129")
```

We'll interpolate the data, and stick that in a data frame.

```
datmat <- interp(dat$x, dat$y, dat$signal, 
                 xo = seq(0, 1, length = 1000),
                 yo = seq(0, 1, length = 1000))
datmat2 <- melt(datmat$z)
names(datmat2) <- c('x', 'y', 'value')
datmat2[,1:2] <- datmat2[,1:2]/1000 # scale it back
```

I'm going to borrow from some previous answers. The `circleFun` below is from [Draw a circle with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862742/draw-a-circle-with-ggplot2).

```
circleFun <- function(center = c(0,0),diameter = 1, npoints = 100){
  r = diameter / 2
  tt <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
  xx <- center[1] + r * cos(tt)
  yy <- center[2] + r * sin(tt)
  return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
}

circledat <- circleFun(c(.5, .5), 1, npoints = 100) # center on [.5, .5]

# ignore anything outside the circle
datmat2$incircle <- (datmat2$x - .5)^2 + (datmat2$y - .5)^2 < .5^2 # mark
datmat2 <- datmat2[datmat2$incircle,]
```

And I really liked the look of the contour plot in [R plot filled.contour() output in ggpplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330821/r-plot-filled-contour-output-in-ggpplot2), so we'll borrow that one.

```
ggplot(datmat2, aes(x, y, z = value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  stat_contour(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = 'polygon', binwidth = 0.01) +
  geom_contour(colour = 'white', alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", na.value = NA) + 
  geom_path(data = circledat, aes(x, y, z = NULL)) +
  # draw the nose (haven't drawn ears yet)
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(0.45, 0.5, .55), y = c(1, 1.05, 1)), 
            aes(x, y, z = NULL)) +
  # add points for the electrodes
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x, y, z = NULL, fill = NULL), 
             shape = 21, colour = 'black', fill = 'white', size = 2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

With improvements mentioned in the comments (setting `extrap = TRUE` and `linear = FALSE` in the `interp` call to fill in gaps and do a spline smoothing, respectively, and removing NAs before plotting), we get:

[image]

---

`mgcv` can do spherical splines. This replaces `akima` (the chunk containing interp() isn't necessary).

```
library(mgcv)
spl1 <- gam(signal ~ s(x, y, bs = 'sos'), data = dat)
# fine grid, coarser is faster
datmat2 <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = seq(0, 1, 0.001), y = seq(0, 1, 0.001)))
resp <- predict(spl1, datmat2, type = "response")
datmat2$value <- resp
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, especially as a ‘potential start’, many thanks! Unfortunately, there seem to be a couple of issues, mainly that a) the last call takes about 40 seconds on an Intel i7 4790K while Matlab toolboxes manage to generate these almost instantly (why is that?), b) I'm getting warnings about removed rows, and c) the plot appears to be ‘sliced’ around the central part (see my updated question in a couple of minutes, please). In case you're willing to play with it, I've also added full data for a given time point just below the original sample.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Not only it looks great and does the job but your description is also very educational. It still takes plenty of time but I've noticed that if I reduce `interp() xo/yo = length` to 100, it looks _practically_ the same and only takes about 3 seconds. Raising `stat_countour() binwidth to 0.1` makes it almost instantaneous. The edges are a bit rough (the bigger the image, the more ‘pixelated’ edges) but perhaps there's a way of extending the fill a bit outside the circle and then cutting it off by masking the outside? See my update.

Comment: Also if you have the chance to look at how EEGLAB does it, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: One more thing, if I may: at certain other time points of my data, the plot appears to contain patterns such as prominent straight lines between colour levels (I mean the contrast between colours) which shouldn't be there (even without the tweaks to speed it up). Is this due to issues with interpolation? Can it be fixed?

Comment: Try the new splines and see what you get. The rough edges can be a new (separate) question. I'm going to delete some comments to clean up too.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work but I'm getting an error at `te(bs = 'sos')`: `Error in smooth.construct.sos.smooth.spec(object$margin[[i]], dat, knt) : Can only deal with a sphere`. Most other smooth terms are working fine but I'm not going to pretend I understand what the differences are. The number of those straight contrast lines has been reduced though.

Comment: I might have accidentally copied a failed tensor spline attempt, give it a go with `s()` rather than `te()`.