# Topoplot of results from EEG data with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, eeglab

**Can I use ggplot to create a topoplot of regression results from some EEG data?**

Essentially I want to do something like this: [topoplot in ggplot2 – 2D visualisation of e.g. EEG data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019382/topoplot-in-ggplot2-2d-visualisation-of-e-g-eeg-data)
while my data is not voltage but results (e.g., coefficients, t-values, Bayes factors, etc) from regression.

I managed to replicate that example where the voltages are plotted. In my attempt, I had a list of Bayes factors from each electrode at a certain time slice. However, I wasn't able to adapt the code in that post to mine. Here is a section of my data:

[Example data](https://gist.github.com/PenelopeLQ/6ce19fd2bc3eef83b84366b03a1c53f6)

This is what I did after importing the data:

[R code](https://gist.github.com/PenelopeLQ/ef86d454ba275c5a806f5eb18c08a081)

Following the code, my predicted values would become the same for all electrodes, or a gradient.

[image: Failed example from one time slice]

I got this only after I executed this section of the ggplot command:

```
ggplot(datmat2, aes(x, y, z = value)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
    stat_contour(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = 'polygon', binwidth = 0.01) +
    geom_contour(colour = 'white', alpha = 0.5) +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", na.value = NA) + 
    geom_path(data = circledat, aes(x, y, z = NULL))
```

If I went on with the rest, the graph turned to this:
[image]

I think the problem occurred when I did the interpolation. Or, it could be because the co-ordinates of the electrodes were different. I'm really a novice with how topoplot and interpolation works, so please bear with me if I've made a dumb mistake.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The Example Data and R Code links are broken

Comment: @eipi10 Oops! sorry! First time. Just a minute.

Comment: @eipi10 Just fixed it.