# R - Contour plot from raster dataset with country borders overlaid

Tags: r, maps, raster, contour

I have a fairly simple and probably common task, plotting a raster dataset with countour lines and adding country borders together in one plot, however I did not find a solution anywhere. There are a a few hints available (such as [this one](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/plot-filled-contour-over-continent-map-td906248.html)), but no raster dataset is used there and I can't get it to work. 
The dataset I am using is actually in netcdf format and available [here](ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/gpcp/precip.mon.mean.nc) (15mb in size) and contains about 40 years of gridded precipitation data. 
Here is my line of code:

```
setwd("...netcdf Data/GPCP")
library("raster") 
library("maps")

nc_brick79_17 <- brick("precip.mon.mean.nc") # load in the ncdf data as a 
raster brick
newextent <- c(85, 125, -20, 20) # specify region of interest
SEA_brick <- crop(nc_brick79_17, newextent) # crop the region
day1 <- SEA_brick[[1]] # select very first day as example
colfunc<-colorRampPalette(c("white","lightblue","yellow","red","purple")) # colorscale for plotting
```

So it works of course when I just plot the raster data together with a map overlaid:

```
plot(day1, col=(colfunc(100)), interpolate=F, main="day1",legend.args=list(text='mm/hr', side=4,font=1, line=2.5, cex=1.1))
map("world", add=TRUE, lwd=0.5, interior = FALSE, col = "black")
```

We get this plot (Raster Plot with country borders added)

[image]

Now the code I use to generate the contour plot is the following:

```
filledContour(day1,zlim=c(0,20),color=colorRampPalette(c("white","lightblue","yellow","red","purple")), 
              xlab = "Longitude (°)", ylab = "Latitude (°)")
map("world", add=TRUE, lwd=0.5, interior = FALSE, col = "black") # add map overlay
```

I end up with a plot where obviously the country borders do not align and are even covering the colorbar.

Contour plot with map overlay shifted

[image]

In this last part I am trying to add the country boundaries to the contour plot, but it does not work, even though it should I assume. The map is simply not there, no error though:

```
filledContour(day1, zlim=c(0,20), 
               color.palette = colorRampPalette(c("white","lightblue","yellow","red","purple")), 
               xlab = "Longitude (°)", ylab = "Latitude (°)", 
               xlim = c(90, 120), ylim = c(-20, 20), nlevels = 25, 
               plot.axes = {axis(1); axis(2);    
               map('world', xlim = c(90, 120), ylim = c(-20, 20), add = TRUE, lwd=0.5, col = "black")})
```

From that line of code I get this plot.

Contour plot but no country borders added

[image]

What could I improve or is there any mistake somewhere? Thank you!

Comment: I've been looking into your case and learning about functions in the raster package now. If you type `?filled.countour` in your R Console, you will see a help page. You will see the following text: `The output produced by filled.contour is actually a combination of two plots; one is the filled contour and one is the legend. Two separate coordinate systems are set up for these two plots, but they are only used internally – once the function has returned these coordinate systems are lost.` This seems to indicate that, by the time you add a map, coordinates are not matching.

Comment: That is, when you draw the contour, you have the plot and the legend. By the time R finished drawing them, there is no coordinate info. Then, you try to add a map with coordinates. That is why there is the mismatch in the final output. I am still not sure if there is a good work around right now.

Comment: Thanks for the details, you are right. I was assuming it should work as that is what they said in my link from above (old forum post from 2009), they also mentioned that according to the help page in filled.contour, it does not seem possible but that it is also mentioned there how to do a work around. So I used that part of their code which apparently worked for them, but did not work in my example here.

Comment: My feeling is that it would be hard to find a workaround with filled.contour. If you are happy to learn some basic ggplot functions, you would be able to make a progress in your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chose to use ggplot here. I leave two maps for you. The first one is the one you created. This is a replication with ggplot. The second one is the one you could not produce. There are many things to explain. But I am afraid I do not have enough time to write all. But I left some comments in my code below. Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330821/r-plot-filled-contour-output-in-ggpplot2) to learn more about the second graphic. Finally, I'd like to give credit to hrbrmstr who wrote a great answer in the linked question.

```
library(maptools)
library(akima)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

# This is a data set from the maptools package
data(wrld_simpl)

# Create a data.frame object for ggplot. ggplot requires a data frame.

mymap <- fortify(wrld_simpl)

# This part is your code.

nc_brick79_17 <- brick("precip.mon.mean.nc")
newextent <- c(85, 125, -20, 20)
SEA_brick <- crop(nc_brick79_17, newextent)
day1 <- SEA_brick[[1]]


# Create a data frame with a raster object. This is a spatial class
# data frame, not a regular data frame. Then, convert it to a data frame.

spdf <- as(day1, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
mydf <- as.data.frame(spdf)
colnames(mydf) <- c("value", "x", "y")


# This part creates the first graphic that you drew. You draw a map.
# Then, you add tiles on it. Then, you add colors as you wish.
# Since we have a world map data set, we trim it at the end.

ggplot() +
geom_map(data = mymap, map = mymap, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id), fill = "white", color = "black") +
geom_tile(data = mydf, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value), alpha = 0.4) + 
scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("white", "lightblue", "yellow", "red", "purple")) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(85, 125), expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c( -20, 20), expand = c(0, 0)) +
coord_equal()
```

[image]

**ggplot version of filled.contour()**

```
# As I mentioned above, you want to study the linked question for this part.

mydf2 <- with(mydf, interp(x = x, 
                           y = y, 
                           z = value,
                           xo = seq(min(x), max(x), length = 400),
                           duplicate = "mean"))

gdat <- interp2xyz(mydf2, data.frame = TRUE)

# You need to draw countries as lines here. You gotta do that after you draw
# the contours. Otherwise, you will not see the map.

ggplot(data = gdat, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) + 
stat_contour(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon", binwidth = 0.007) + 
geom_contour(color = "white") +
geom_path(data = mymap, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(85, 125), expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-20, 20), expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("white", "lightblue", "yellow", "red", "purple")) +
coord_equal() +
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help! Just followed your code, it works fine!! I am not familiar with ggplot at all, so I will have to dive into that. Just a bit slow when plotting the contour figure, seems to be calculation intensive.

Comment: @DomJack I needed a good amount of time to learn this by myself. For the sample data, calculation is not that bad. You just need to wait for a couple of seconds or so. If you have more data, it will take some time for sure. Thanks to your question, I am learning bilinear interpolation in imaging now. If your case is done, please press the green tick staying just under the voting triangles. In this way, future readers will know that the solution works.